# Any open Souce API for Yahoo Chat on Android?

Tags: android, chat, yahoo

Is there any open source API for using Yahoo chat on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [jymsg9](http://jymsg9.sourceforge.net/) but I never used it.

Comment: Yes, i also got the same, but wondering how to use... Can anyone help me out with some sample codes for yahoo chat...