# Android Yahoo/MSN Chat Implementation

Tags: android, msn-messenger, yahoo-messenger

I am developing an Android application where it needs to integrate social chat like yahoo and msn. I have searched for the implementation of both [yahoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360125/any-open-souce-api-for-yahoo-chat-on-android) and msn but nothing got succeeded yet. Can anybody kindly suggest any links or any tutorials available, where I can get the correct idea for implementing yahoo or msn chats. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

There is an implemetation of jYMSG (http://jymsg9.sourceforge.net/) for android here (only the source code inside a svn repo): http://code.google.com/p/aymsg/ .

This one is a more secure implementation of MSN for Android http://code.google.com/p/galoula-messenger-http/ . Same problem, no documentation, only source code.

They worked for me with some minor changes, I hope it will give you a correct idea of what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use opensource msn sdk for retrieving auth token.
Here is the git repo  https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android

This will help you up to some extent for msn integration.

Answer (score 1):

To implement yahoo messenger chat in your android application, you have to use yahoo IM SDK in your project given here http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/

All other projects are dead. And above given implementation works very much fine. You can try this library given at GIT  https://github.com/aldrinm/messenger-sdk.